# Highlight Data After Success in jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating an *inline editing* in my webpage through jquery Ajax.

In my code I can edit the Table Data but I want To *highlight the changed data for few seconds of editing*.

I applied Many code Like:

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

But it is not Giving Me proper result

Here is My PHP code:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {


        echo "<tr>";

        echo '<td>'.$rows["id"].'</td>
        <td class="edit uname '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["uname"].'</td>
        <td class="edit pass '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["pass"].'</td>

        </tr>';
    }
```

And Here Is My jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.edit').click(function(){
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        $(this).addClass('ajax');
        $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        $('#editbox').focus();
    });

    $('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
        arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        if(event.which == 13) { 
            $.ajax({    
                type: "POST",
                url:"config.php",
                data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rownum="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
                success: function(data){
                    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                    $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "highlight" );
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#editbox').live('blur',function(){
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });

});

</script>
```

So please help me friends.

Comment: did you mean you want the row to highlight when you clicked edit?

Comment: Yes Either Entire row or just text of Table row Data

Comment: Here I posted an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adding the highlight effect on your td.edit click event

```
 $('td.edit').click(function(){

        $(this).parent().effect("highlight", {}, 3000); //create highlight effect on parent tr

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        $(this).addClass('ajax');
        $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        $('#editbox').focus();
    });
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremejazz/xmLTE/)

Comment: No I write $(this).parent().effect("highlight", {}, 3000);  before Whole code of td edit but it is not working even after putting code when i click on code it is nor converting in textbox

Comment: well what sort of output would you like? It is supposed make the parent tr of the td you clicked to glow unless you would like something else to happen

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jQuery UI which has the highlight effect, you could do:

```
$(this).effect( "highlight",5000);
```

_Note: For this you need the jQuery UI [Library](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MUr72/)**

or without the jQuery UI, you can do:

```
$(this).css('background-color','yellow');
setTimeout(function() {$(this).css('background-color','');}, 3000).fadeOut();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pm7T3/)**

Comment: But Where can I Write this code  I write this code after in ajax success but it is not working for this I also add div tag to td

Comment: @user3489725 Could you explain what your code does?

Comment: Now I Write                                                    $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
setTimeout(function() {$(this).css('background-color','');}, 3000).fadeOut(); in keydown event it makes td background yellow but it does not remove it after few seconds

Comment: @user3489725 If it's on a `keydown` event, then according to the above code you need to wait for 3 seconds after pressing the key. How does the inline editing work? The user presses enter after editing the text or clicks on some button?

Comment: My inline editing Work when the user presses enter after pressing text and after pressing enter I wait for 3 seconds but it is not working When user press enter it makes background yellow but it is not going back after 3 seconds

Comment: @user3489725 Can you check if your console is showing any errors?

Comment: Yes my Console Showing This Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: But I Include Javascript Writing <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in Head

Comment: @user3489725 You are getting confused. jQuery and jQuery UI are separate libraries. For the second method you do not need jQuery UI. And you do have jQuery library included right?

Comment: Now I Write <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> before Closing Head and Console error disappeared

Comment: I remove that jquery ui file from my page but diffrence in result